# Explaining Berlekamp-Massey Algorithm in simple/layman term?

Tags: algorithm-design, lfsr

My foundation in Mathematics is not great. But I would like to understand how Berlekamp-Massey Algorithm works and how it is used in lay-man terms.

The only thing I find out there is the emphasis on discrepancy and how to make it zero (which means no discrepancy), and it is used to determine the minimal polynomial factor to produce sequence of bits.

The resources out there are full of mathematical equations which I do not understand, and to be honest, I don't know where to start. But I don't want to give up.

*I'll appreciate any resources or books which are simple enough for a young student.*

Comment: Well, without the discrepancy, it is hard to describe. One can say that with the $2n$ unknowns, one can setup linear equations and solve them in $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$-time, whereas BM archives this in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$-time

Comment: I don't think being "young" is the issue. I mean we can say that the algorithm drives the discrepancy to zero recursively, but it's as vague as what you wrote.